# jQuery each div for first level

Tags: html, jquery

I have the next HTML.

```
<div id="id">
   <div>
      <div class="permissions">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And in jQuery I use loop.

```
$("#id div").each(function(){
   //do something
});
```

This loop run by all divs in #id. How make the same loop only by divs of the first level?
Thank you in advance. Sorry for my english.

Comment: I wouldn't give anything an id of "id" though. (If this isn't just an example.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By having a space between `#id` and `div`, you're using [a descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).

Instead, use [a `>` child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

```
$("#id > div").each(function(){
   //do something
});
```

Now it will only target `<div>` elements that are a direct descendant (child) of `#id`.

It is the equivalent of using `.children()` instead of `.find()`:

```
   // only direct descendant divs
$("#id").children("div").each(function() {
   //do something
});


   // all descendant divs
$("#id").find("div").each(function() {
   //do something
});
```